# Document Processing using AI

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

Deal all

I want to Build a Document Processing AI Model
1-that Identify Document Elements
Like table, Text , List , Heading ,  etc.
2-Sort this element in correct way if I wan to dump this data as XML

so I attached two images the first one the original image
the second one show me the expectation output recognize Document Elements and the sort Index for each item
you can see the Sort not follow a regular sort

I already build a model using some Tensor flow and train my Model with a lot of documents Classes elements and model recognize me the Boundary box + Class Name as Shown in the third image ,
so my missing part how to predict the correctly order for this elements

I've a good dataset that I can extract the sort data to use while training the model
but I don't know which thing will match my needs
any help

[image: Original Image]

[image: Processing iamge]

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to rank the elements that are detected and how.

Comment: this very important to help blind people to read document in the correct orders using some application that read tag and it's attribute and convert this to sound
any web page contain some HTML tags that the blind people can access it through some accessibility roles and reader use the HTML Tags to interpreter the page 
H1 read with high volume , H2 read will a smaller , if there is image and there is alt text so it read the alt text , tables , charts ,..etc.
so it should listen to the content in the correct order